# Householder Reflection of a vector

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra

I want to construct a Householder reflection of a vector. My attempt is below according to the algorithm.

```
import math
import numpy as np
def vector_norm(n , vec):
    result = 0
    for k in range (n ):
       result = result + vec[k] * vec[k]
    return math.sqrt(result)

def householder(vec):
    #vec the vector to be transformed
    vec = np.asarray(vec, dtype=float)
    if vec.ndim != 1:
         raise ValueError("vec.ndim = %s, expected 1" % vec.ndim)

    n = len(vec)
    I = np.eye(n)
    e1 = np.asarray(([0.0]*n),dtype=float)
    e1[0] = 1.0
    V1 = vec - vector_norm(n , vec)*e1
    V_trans = np.array([V1])
    H = I - 2 * ((V_trans.T @ V_trans) / vector_norm( n ,V1))
    return V1 , H
```

However, when I check;

```
v = np.array([1, 2, 3])
v1, h = householder(v)
assert_allclose(np.dot(h, v1), v)
assert_allclose(np.dot(h, v), v1)
```

The result is wrong.

```
AssertionError: 
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0

(mismatch 100.0%)
x: array([ 22.095208, -16.118139, -24.177209])
y: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: The householder matrix from a vector x is I - 2*v*v'/(v'*v). In other words in your second last line you should divide by the square of the vector norm.

Comment: Yes the missing step was that I need to divide v1 by is norm before taking the transpose.

Comment: If you still happen to have the code, could you share it? Because I did what is said in these comments, and nothing happened